# Enterprise wiki site collection Users privileges in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, wiki, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have created a collaboration site collection which contain an enterprise wiki, and now my register users are being able to add, edit, delete and read wikis in a very reliable and efficient way.
But now users are asking for these extra requirements, but unfortunately i cannot find enough documentation on how to implement these requirements for my enterprise wiki site:-

1. Some managers ask that they want only certain users to be able to add wiki under certain categories, for example our HR manager ask me to prevent non-HR users for adding any wikis under the “HR Manuals” category.
2. I need to allow the creator of a wiki to be able to either:-

   -Directly publish his wiki to all users. This can happen when the user is confident about the accuracy of the wiki info.

   -OR if he is not certain about the information inside the wiki, he shouldbe able to send the wiki for approval to selected user to review his wiki before publishing it to all users.
3. Finally as i am the site collection admin, i need to prevent user –of course except me- from adding wiki categories ?

So can anyone help me in how i can achieve these requirements as i fail to find relevant documentation about these points?

Thanks in advance for any help
Best Regards

Comment: Must everything live in a single wiki?  For example, I definitely see HR and Benefits content as different, and would typically look to house that in a separate wiki site.

Comment: so you mean it is better to create separate site collections for each department. so that i might have different URLs such as http://sp/HR && http://sp/technical && http://sp/sales , etc. ???? thanks

Comment: By creating different wiki sites you can secure it at the site level.  They wouldn't have to necessarily have to be different site collections.

Comment: Can you offer me with relevant links which describe your point in more details. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple site *collections* but you would do well to get multiple sites.

Perhaps create a "Wiki Center" as a top-level site which houses all of your Wikis. You can then create each "Wiki" beneath it as a sub-site so each of your distinct "Wikis" can have different permissions, workflows, policies and even tagging / metadata if you want?

You can then use Search or Content Query to aggregate your wiki content back up to the top level so that users can browse / navigate / search for Wiki Content.

You might also want to look at leveraging some of the new analytics fields in Search so you can start to surface content with "most views" or "most likes" ..

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. but all the documentations i have read just mentioned how to create a new wiki as a new site collection. So can you refer to me of some links and documentations which can help me in understanding how to create a top-level Wiki and then create sub sites which have separate security settings? thanks

Comment: Site Contents - Add Sub site..

Select the "Enterprise Wiki" (in the "Publishing" category) as the selected site template.